# Jinja2 UndefinedError accessing specific elements of a list

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

In my python flask code I have stored a list of numbers in a session and rendered it to my html page:

```
return render_template("solved.html", ambiguousCase=session['ambTrue'], angles=session['angles'], sides=session['sides'])
```

I have tried to access specific elements of the list in a variety of ways:

```
<label>Angle of A = {{ angles.0 }}</label>
<label>Angle of B = {{ angles.0 }}</label>
<label>Angle of C = {{ angles.2 }}</label>
<label>Side Length of a = {{ sides.0 }}</label>
<label>Side Length of b = {{ sides.1 }}</label>
<label>Side Length of c = {{ sides.2 }}</label>
```

and

```
<label>Angle of A = {{ angles[0] }}</label>
<label>Angle of B = {{ angles[1] }}</label>
<label>Angle of C = {{ angles[2] }}</label>
<label>Side Length of a = {{ sides[0] }}</label>
<label>Side Length of b = {{ sides[1] }}</label>
<label>Side Length of c = {{ sides[2] }}</label>
```

Both methods give me this error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'angles' is undefined
```

I know in jinja you can use a for loop to access elements of a list:

```
{% for angle in angles %}
      <h1>{{ angle }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

But I don't think that can apply to my code.
What error am I making?

Comment: In your position I've be very temped to add a `print(session['angles'])` to ensure that the template is getting passed something sensible.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith It prints a list floats which is the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Instead of using the redirect function I was using the render_template function.
So the path I had defining all of the variables was never being called

Mistake on my part